# I have my buddy Feebas and have walked 20km with it. Is it too late to evolve?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is it too late for me to complete this special research?
Feebas with 20km and over 109 candies still will not evolve?

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the research asking? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I still can't see the special research you're talking about...

Comment: Something has gone wrong in that rightmost screenshot. It should be showing the CP values and the league names. Restart your app and that screen should fix itself (and make more sense)

Answer (score 4):

To evolve Feebas you are required to set it as your buddy and walk a minimum of 20km with it. Once you have completed this task, you can then freely evolve it.

The notification you are receiving about choosing to evolve it, is only in regards to the [Pokemon Go Battle League](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_GO_Battle_League). There are "caps" of 1500 CP, and 2500 CP. Evolving your pokemon may automatically boost their CP beyond one of these caps, which is unavoidable.

There is nothing in regards to this choice being "too late", as this is standard practice for Feebas/Milotic evolution

Answer (score 1):

That specific error screen appears when the game *thought* that you were able to evolve, but upon clicking the button you were no longer able to. This can occur for any of the following reasons:

- The selected Pokemon is no longer in your storage (has been transferred)
- You no longer have the required evolution item (obviously not relevant to Feebas)
- The selected Pokemon was already evolved
- You no longer have the required candy

The first two options there likely can not happen unless you're running multiple copies of the game simultaneously, but the 3rd and 4th options can occur if there's significant network or server issues while you attempt to evolve.

I believe that it is also possible during Adventure Sync synchronisations for distance to correct itself downwards, in which case this error *may* appear if the game estimates that you've walked 20km, gives you the evolve button, and then right before you click it synchronises with your phone's fitness tracker and realises you haven't actually quite gotten there yet.

In all cases, simply restarting the application should resolve to the correct application state. You may see that an evolve was actually successful and you already have your Milotic, or you may just see an unevolved Feebas that should now be possible to evolve without error. In either case, there should be no major blockade to completing that evolution requirement after an application restart.